# Connection with the sockets on Android or IOS to Sails js

Tags: javascript, android, sockets, socket.io, sails.js

Is there is an library which is connecting to sails.socket on android and ios? Tested sockets on front with it's own lib that comes along but now facing problem with connecting android to sailsjs sockets